# Python doctests embedded in README.md: "Expected: ``` Got nothing"

Tags: python, markdown, doctest

I have a markdown file `README.md` containing the following code block at the start, and various other code blocks throughout:

````
```python
>>> import mypackage
```
````

I am trying to use doctest to verify that the code in `README.md` all runs correctly by calling

```sh
$ doctest README.md
```

which I expect to output something like

```
   docs: commands succeeded
   congratulations :)
```

since the tests are so simple. Instead, at the end of each block, I get an error message along the lines of

````
Failed example:
    import mypackage
Expected:
    ```
Got nothing
````

indicating to me that doctest is interpreting the closing backticks of my code block as expected output. I have temporarily resolved the issue by adding a newline before the closing backticks of each code block. I.e.

````
```python
>>> import mypackage

```
````

However, this feels kludgy and forces me to remember to add the newline to any new code blocks I add in the future.

**Is there a right way to have doctest ignore the closing backticks of markdown code blocks?**

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized), a blank line indicates the end of the expected output. Without it, the example is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe! In that case I might just preprocess my .md files before and after running the doctests to add and remove newlines.